# Web3.eth.getAccoutns() not working after Update

Tags: javascript, web3js, truffle, metamask, ganache

I'm developing an dapp using truffle/ganache/metamask/vue. Everything was going fine until I updated Google Chrome and Metamask's extension. Now I can't get the account logged in metamask anymore.

I already try to call the getAccounts() with the async/await, promises, etc. Nothing works altough I'm logged in in metamask and I'm able to see my balance, transfer eth to another account.... It's also curious that web3 is being injected normally in the browser.

This is in the main.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('Web3 injected browser: OK.')
    Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send;

    window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
  } else {
    console.log('Web3 injected browser: Fail. You should consider trying MetaMask.')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send;
    
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
  }
```

This is in a Vue Component

```
        window.web3.eth.getAccounts((err, res) => {  
          if (err){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(err)
          }                 
          console.log(res[0]);
});
```

I was expecting the console log to print my wallet address instead of "undefined". The array web3.eth.accounts is always empty now.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I already found the problem. In new version of Metamask, the privacy mode is, by default, activated. I just had to turn it off and started working properly.